# Post variables not being sent

Tags: php, variables, post

This is really bugging me and I can't figure it out. I have a form with a few options being sent by POST:

```
<form method="POST" action="scripts/submit.php"><strong>
    To User: <input type="text" name="ID" size="21" /><br />
    Short Description: <input type="text" name="Item" size="21" /><br />
    Link: <input type="text" name="Link" size="21" /><br />
    Points: <select name="Points">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="0">0</option><option value="-1">-1</option>
    </select> (1 = Positive, 0 = Neutral, -1 = Negative)<br />
    Text: <br /><textarea name="Text" rows="5" cols="50"/></textarea></strong><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

And here is the portion of submit.php that is giving me trouble:

```
<?php
include('functions.php');
Connect();

if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
session_start(); 
} 
$id_from = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
$id_to = Sanitize($_POST['ID']);
$item = Sanitize($_POST['Item']);
$link = Sanitize($_POST['Link']);
$points= Sanitize($_POST['points']);
$text = Sanitize($_POST['Text']);
```

Does anyone see an issue here? I am getting undefined index's from all of the variables except the session one.

Thanks in advance.

edit: If i just have this:

```
<?php
include('functions.php');
Connect();
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
session_start(); 
} 

$id_from = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
$id_to = Sanitize($_POST['ID']);
$item = Sanitize($_POST['Item']);
$link = Sanitize($_POST['Link']);
$points = Sanitize($_POST['points']);
$text = Sanitize($_POST['Text']);

?>
```

The variables populate just fine. If I add:

```
 $id_query=mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM tbl_users WHERE Username = '$id_to'");

 $count=mysql_num_rows($id_query);

 $id_row=mysql_fetch_array($id_query);
 $id_to=$id_row['ID'];

 if ($points> 1 || $points< -1) {
     echo "Nice try";
     exit();
 } else {

 if(!($id_to == $id_from))
 {
 if($count==1)
 {
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_data (Item, Link, Points, Text, ID_To, ID_From) VALUES ('$item', '$link', '$points', '$text', '$id_to','$id_from')");
 header('Location:?id=submit');
 }
 else
 {
 echo "Nice try1";
 }
 }
 else
 {
 echo "Nice try2";
 }
 }
```

Comment: In a `<form>` method attribute, the `post` has to be lowercased.

Comment: Try doing `var_dump($_POST);` to get a full output of what's in it.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt I tried it lowercase, same issue.

Comment: @DCo Works fine for me with your HTML.. http://j-li.net/test/test3.html

Comment: yup - agree with @jli - works fine - perhaps you want to check what `functions.php` and `Connect()` do, who knows there are something like `$_POST = array()` somewhere ;)

Comment: +1 Yeah that's what I was about to say.

Comment: Of course to be sure you can `var_dump($_POST);` before doing anything else at all.

Comment: @Riyono functions.php just has a list of functions, and connect() just connects to mysql database.

Comment: @DCo Can you try dumping `$_POST` right at the beginning of your file?

Comment: Huh I'm quite confused then. Maybe it's an issue with server setup?

Comment: @jli WAMP server and was running fine earlier :| I want to jump off of a bridge because of this...

Comment: All I can think of is to packet sniff and check if the postdata is actually getting sent..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just took your code over at my dev server at tried to test run it. Since I don't know what your Sanitize() do, I can't be sure what is going on inside this function.

If you try to remove the Sanitize(), I'm pretty sure it would work and you will have to look inside this to find the bug.

I'm guessing you might be missing something like ($var, str) for sanitize a string. Can you please tell a little more about this function ?

edit: some minor spelling errors.

Edit: Did some more test and made the error happen and the two codes shows it. The 1st works, while the 2nd gives me a empty var_dump.

This one gives me a full var_dump();

```
<?
function Sanitize($String) { 
$output = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($String));
return $output;
}
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
session_start(); 
} 
?>
<form method="post" action=""><strong>
To User: <input type="text" name="ID" size="21" /><br />
Short Description: <input type="text" name="Item" size="21" /><br />
Link: <input type="text" name="Link" size="21" /><br />
Points: <select name="Points"><option value="1" selected="selected">1</option><option value="0">0</option><option value="-1">-1</option></select> (1 = Positive, 0 = Neutral, -1 = Negative)<br />
Text: <br /><textarea name="Text" rows="5" cols="50"/></textarea></strong><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

<?

$id_from = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
$id_to = Sanitize($_POST['ID']);
$item = Sanitize($_POST['Item']);
$link = Sanitize($_POST['Link']);
$points= Sanitize($_POST['points']);
$text = Sanitize($_POST['Text']);


var_dump($_POST);

echo $text;

?>
```

This one gives me an empty var_dump

```
<?
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
session_start(); 
} 
?>
<form method="post" action=""><strong>
To User: <input type="text" name="ID" size="21" /><br />
Short Description: <input type="text" name="Item" size="21" /><br />
Link: <input type="text" name="Link" size="21" /><br />
Points: <select name="Points"><option value="1" selected="selected">1</option><option value="0">0</option><option value="-1">-1</option></select> (1 = Positive, 0 = Neutral, -1 = Negative)<br />
Text: <br /><textarea name="Text" rows="5" cols="50"/></textarea></strong><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

<?

$id_from = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
$id_to = Sanitize($_POST['ID']);
$item = Sanitize($_POST['Item']);
$link = Sanitize($_POST['Link']);
$points= Sanitize($_POST['points']);
$text = Sanitize($_POST['Text']);


var_dump($_POST);

echo $text;

?>
```

Comment: `function Sanitize($String) { //Sanitizes data from MySQL injections
 $output = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($String));
 return $output;
}`

edit: removing sanitize does not fix the problem.

Comment: Okay, try remove eveything from scripts/submit.php so the only thing showing up in your submit.php is the following:

`<? var_dump($_POST); ?>`

Is it ging anythign ?

Comment: If that is all that is there, then yes it passes the variables.

Comment: Then try inserting one line at the time from the top to see when the var_dump($_POST) is empty.. Make sure var_dump($_POST) is always placed as the last line

Comment: Let me show you the rest of the script - when that is added things seem to go south:

`$id_query=mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM tbl_users WHERE Username = '$id_to'");

$count=mysql_num_rows($id_query);

$id_row=mysql_fetch_array($id_query);
$id_to=$id_row['ID'];

if ($points> 1 || $points< -1) {
} else {

if(!($id_to == $id_from))
    {
    if($count==1)
        {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_data (Item, Link) VALUES ('$item', '$link')");
        header('Location:?id=submit');
        }
    else
        {
        
        }
    }
else
    {
    
    }
}`

Comment: that was rather hard to read. If you tried with **ONLY** the code you posted in your question in your submit php and it shows up in the var_dump, then i have no clue. Only last chance is to change your `mysql_query();` to `mysql_query() or die(mysql_error());` (remember to include your SQL)

Comment: @CasperO Did you try reading the comments on the question? We had this discussion already.

Comment: @jli well i just did. Sorry about that. But as you can read from these comments you would also see that $_POST is being send, making me belive that it is something with his connect or Sanitize. (or any other part of submit.php not included in the question).

Comment: @CasperO The thing is that he tried dumping `$_POST` at the start of the file, before doing anything else at all. Still an empty array.

Comment: @jli i asked him to empty his submit.php and also do a var_dump() and from what he said it passes the variables.. But since I seems to be in the way I would leave you guys..

Comment: @CasperO No you're not in the way, I don't know the answer either. It's just that we had already determined that the problem likely isn't in the PHP file.

Comment: @jli Whenever I add the second part of the code the post array becomes empty. And I never move the code of the post array, and nothing new comes before it

Comment: @jli okay, then i have one more shot. From the info we have been given the only way i can make my var_dump of $_POST empty is by removing Sanitize function from the top of my script. Is Sanitize a part of your functions.php or not ?

Comment: It is part of it. Also, even if I put the dump at the top of the script it will be empty, even before sanitize.

Comment: Then I am really sorry, I have no more idea how to solve your problem then. It seems like a small error but I'm on deep water at this point. The Sanitize where the only thing that made my test thing go blank. Crossing my fingers for @jli have some idea left in the pocket.

Comment: @DCo I can't follow what you're saying. "Whenever I add the second part of the code" What is the second part? Are both of the parts you show in your question in the same file? Otherwise can you update your question to show when it works and when it stops working?

Comment: @DCo I haven't tested in detail but can you verify that you're not ending up in the script you get taken to by the header? Can you comment the header out?

Comment: @Dan yes I am not ending up there.

Comment: Sorry there is nothing I see that could cause the var_dump output an empty array then if you place it at the top of your sumbit.php. Are you sure other parts are not relevant?

Comment: Please take this troubleshooting thread to a chat room instead of the comment system.

Answer (score 1):

based on your comment that you have this code:

```
$id_query = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM tbl_users WHERE Username = '$id_to'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($id_query);
$id_row = mysql_fetch_array($id_query);
$id_to = $id_row['ID'];
if ($points > 1 || $points < -1) {

} else {
    if (! ($id_to == $id_from)) {
        if ($count == 1) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_data (Item, Link) VALUES ('$item', '$link')");
            header('Location:?id=submit');
        } else {}
    } else {}
}
```

I think the problem is on the line that says:

```
header('Location:?id=submit');
```

Perhaps you're testing with something that somehow make `$points` either greater than 1 or less than -1, `$count` is 1, and `$id_to` is different from `$id_from`, which then make the `else` block executed and (especially the line) `header()` executed, and user get redirect immediately.

To check if this is true, try `var_dump($_GET)` to see if you got something like:

```
array (size=1)
  'id' => string 'submit' (length=6)
```

If you do, and perhaps the database isn't updated, then it's the mysql_query that sits right before the header is the one that you need to check.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had a similar issue and a redirect to the same page was the culprit.
I was redirecting to a ?success=1 therefore the _POST was empty after the redirect.